# How to create generic method to return generic type

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I have the following method now

```
private classResponse getClassResponse(final Response response) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(response.getEntity()), classResponse.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error while mapping object: {} to classResponse with cause", response.getEntity(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But for every different class I have to create a new method to convert from response to class

Is there any way that this could be made generic by having one more argument for class name in which I want to convert?

Comment: Write a generic method with a `class` as a parameter.

Comment: `@SuppresWarnings("unchecked") private <T> T getResponse(final Response response, Class<T> tClass) { ... return (T) ...; }`

Comment: @AnatolyG readValue needs the class at runtime to know what class the instance it creates should be.

Comment: What question do you have about writing a generic method?

Comment: @tgdavies then dbl's snippet should work. But, from my point of view, API like that says put any type and you will get result of such type/I can work with any types, but this doesn't seem to be true. I'd prefer to have a number of methods with specific/closed set of supported types defined in/by their signatures

Comment: Create a generic response class with some member variable and add setter getter into that class and use instance of that class in another class for settting and then returning the instance of that class.

Comment: @dbl you can write an answer too.

Comment: @Nitika, I'm happy if I helped. Yet I have no time to do so. You can post your findings and thoughs and **accept** that instead :) If you are still struggling, then I can write an answer later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dbl for the help. Summing up the answer below,

```
private <T> T getResponse(final Response response, final Class<T> className) {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(response.getEntity()), className);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error while mapping object: {} to class with cause", response.getEntity(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```